# How to select rows with single value in pandas dataframe column which has both single value and comma seperated values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which has single values and comma separated values. I want to select those rows with only one value(with no comma) and ignore other rows from a particular column say df['Label'].
so the column values would look like this:

```
a
d,c
a,ab,c
b
e
```

From above I want only the rows a,b,e and drop the rest. I get boolean values in dataframe when
I tried below code:
'''

```
df['multilabel'] = df['Label'].str.contains(',')
df['singlelabel'] = df['multilabel']==False
df
```

'''

Comment: Have you consulted the Pandas documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to fix your code

```
df['multilabel'] = df['Label'].str.contains(',')
df = df[~df['multilabel']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the false muitilable values try after first line:

```
df = df[~df['multilabel']]
```